# Как указать любой другой метод вывода, кроме .forEach(System.out::println)?

Tags: java, циклы

Я считываю байты из файла и добавляю их в `map`. Мне нужно вывести первые 3 значения, но я не знаю как это указать в последних строках кода, кроме как `.forEach(System.out::println)`. В коде есть комментарий где именно мне нужно указать конкретное число итераций для вывода. Буду благодарен всем за помощь!

```
package com.javarush.task.task18.task1803;

/* 
Самые частые байты
*/

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(bf.readLine());

        int count = fileInputStream.available();

        int[] b = new int[count];
        int index = 0;

        while (fileInputStream.available() > 0) {
            b[index++] = fileInputStream.read();
        }

        /*for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i] + " ");
        }*/

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int counter = 1;
        int current = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            current = b[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (current == b[j]) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            map.put(current, counter);
            counter = 1;
        }

        map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()).forEach(System.out::println); // тут
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае в методе `forEach` объявляется переменная, которая на каждой итерации будет принимать значение элемента коллекции, и далее указываются действия с ним.

Пример:

```
.forEach(element -> {
    System.out.println(element);
});
```

Такую запись можно сократить до:

```
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

В вашем случае, *например*, можно в этом же классе `Solution` создать дополнительный метод, принимающий на вход объект коллекции:

```
private static void sout(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

и вызывать его:

```
.forEach(Solution::sout);
```

---

В общем случае метод может быть таким:

```
private static void method(Object object) {
    System.out.println(object);
    // или любые другие действия, на ваше усмотрение..
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Comment: Как легко понять, что лямбду можно заменить ссылкой на метод: если параметр лямбды совпадает с параметром метода, который в этой лямбде вызывается, например, лямбда s -> System.out.println(s) преобразуется в System.out::println